# Как разрешить выполнение скрипта при условиях в урле?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Дано: сайт на CMS.
Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы яваскрипт работал только на определенных страницах сайта (то есть если в урл адресе есть значение "товар")?
Например, есть страницы:

1) сайт/страницатовар;
 2) сайт/товарстраница;
 3) сайт/страница1.

...100500 всяких страниц еще.

Нужно, чтобы яваскрипт выполнялся в первом и втором варианте (так как в этих адресах есть вхождение "товар"). В последней странице он выполняться не должен (поскольку нет вхождения).

Пробовал так:

```
var need_location = '"товар"';  
if (window.location.pathname == need_location){
//Здесь код который выполняться должен на 2х указанный выше страницах только (всплывающее окно)  
}
```

Но не работает...

Прошу помочь в решении задачи. Если такое вообще возможно. Вставлять код только на те страницы, которые нужны, не вариант, так как сайт на cms.